# Not able to write sql query command for the ODBC source

Tags: ssis, odbc

I usually write SQL queries for the ODBC Source connecting to a postgres SQL database. Everything works find until today I found when I hit the database access mode as 'SQL Command', there is no command box for me to type? I have been stuck at this for long time, trying to find the answers online, but was unable to. Any ideas or do I miss anything?

[image]

Comment: What other access modes are available? I assume there's a table picker - does it populate a list of tables? If not, then it smells like driver or credential issues. If yes, then try deleting the ODBC source and re-adding it to the data flow.

Comment: @billinkc yes, I can choose tables, but there is no 'data preview' button for me to view. I tried to delete the source and re-adding, still didn't work.